# Same method for verify empty fields using REST and SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I created different methods for verify if there is empty fields in SOAP and REST services. For Soap i use something like this:

```
 if (fornecedor.isEmpty()) {            
            throw new BadRequestException(error + " fornecedor");
        }
```

For REST i made this:

```
 if (fornecedor.isEmpty()) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, ERROR + " fornecedor");

}
```

It means that I have  @Context HttpServletResponse response as parameter in Rest and nothing on SOAP because it is an exception. There is other way to verify empty fields using same method for SOAP and REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey allows you to map custom exceptions to responses.
The relevant documentation is here:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e5199

Example mapping:

```
@Provider
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException>  {
  public Response toResponse(BadRequestException ex) {
    return Response.status(404).
      entity(ex.getMessage()).
      type("text/plain").
      build();
  }
}
```